# Dynamic CFT Creation and Updating

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, templates, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I have an AWS TEMPLATE:

```
##Some info before this not relevant
  "Parameters": {
    "ResourceBucket": {
      "Description": "S3 bucket of the where the step function resources are stored",
      "Type": "String",
      "Default": "ccs-sandbox-lambda-deploys"
    },
    "StableS3StepFunctionKey": {
      "Description": "S3 Key where the Step Functions templates live",
      "Type": "String"
    },
    "NumQueueUrls": {
      "Description": "Number of Queue URLs to be used in DefinitionSubstitutions",
      "Type": "Number",
      "Default": 3
    },
    "queueUrlValue": {
      "Description": "Queue Url of the Classification Enrichment",
      "Type": "String"
    }
  },
  "Resources": {
           #Random Resources...
    },
    "WorkflowStateMachine": {
      "Type": "AWS::StepFunctions::StateMachine",
      "Properties": {
        "StateMachineName": {
          "Fn::Sub": "abc-WorkflowStateMachine"
        },
        "DefinitionS3Location": {
          "Bucket": {
            "Ref": "ResourceBucket"
          },
          "Key": {
            "Ref": "StableS3StepFunctionKey"
          }
        },
        "DefinitionSubstitutions": {
          "QueueUrl": {
            "Ref": "queueUrlValue"
          }
        },
         
##Rest of the Template
```

I want to dynamically add the parameters and use those dynamically inside the definitionsubsitutions.So something like this If NumQueueUrls is passed as 3 as parameter from my Jenkins, then I have 3 different QueueUrl parameters such as queueUrlValue, queueUrlValue1, queueUrlValue2.

```
"Parameters": {
  "queueUrlValue": {
    "Description": "Queue URL 1",
    "Type": "String",
    "Default": "DefaultQueueUrl1"
  },
  "queueUrlValue1": {
    "Description": "Queue URL 2",
    "Type": "String",
    "Default": "DefaultQueueUrl2"
  },
  "queueUrlValue2": {
    "Description": "Queue URL 3",
    "Type": "String",
    "Default": "DefaultQueueUrl3"
  }
                }
```

and it then updates my definition Subsitution to :

```
        "DefinitionSubstitutions": {
          "QueueUrl": {
            "Ref": "queueUrlValue"
          },
          "QueueUrl1": {
            "Ref": "queueUrlValue1"
          },
          "QueueUrl2": {
            "Ref": "queueUrlValue2"
          }
```

I want this because we want to create similar resources but with different queueURL combinations and maintaining too many similar templates doesn't look ideal solution. So what can be done.

So far I have thought to use Macros inside the DefinitionSubstitutions but then I am not sure how would I be able to add the parameters dynamically in the cft template. Kind of stuck here.